# CakePHP 3.1: Validation for translate behaviour fields (i18n)

Tags: validation, cakephp, internationalization, multilingual, cakephp-3.1

I'm trying to add an item including multiple translations **in one form** with the CakePHP [translate behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html).

**How can I validate the translation fields?** E.g. make specific languages required?

Let's assume you have a simple `items` table with a [separate translations table](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html#using-a-separate-translations-table) `items_i18n`, set up as described in the book. As simple example the `items` table has only one field `title` to translate and I want to save the `title` in five languages. So I make a form like this (in `add` view template):

```php
echo $this->Form->create($item, ['controller' => 'Items', 'action' => 'add']);
echo $this->Form->input('title', ['label' => __('English')]);
echo $this->Form->input('_translations.es.title', ['label' => __('Spanish')]);
echo $this->Form->input('_translations.fr.title', ['label' => __('French')]);
echo $this->Form->input('_translations.de.title', ['label' => __('German')]);
echo $this->Form->input('_translations.it.title', ['label' => __('Italian')]);
echo $this->Form->button(__('Save'), ['type' => 'submit']);
echo $this->Form->end();
```

And saving in the controller (`add` action/function) like this:

```php
$item = $this->Items->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
  $translations = [
    'es' => ['title' => $this->request->data['_translations']['es']['title']],
    'fr' => ['title' => $this->request->data['_translations']['fr']['title']],
    'de' => ['title' => $this->request->data['_translations']['de']['title']],
    'it' => ['title' => $this->request->data['_translations']['it']['title']],
  ];
  foreach ($translations as $lang => $data) {
    $item->translation($lang)->set($data, ['guard' => false]);
  }
  $item = $this->Items->patchEntity($item, $this->request->data, ['validate' => 'default'] );
  if ( $this->Items->save($item) ) { $this->Flash->success(__('Saved.')); }
  else { $this->Flash->error(__('Not saved.')); }
}
$this->set('item', $item);
```

This is working without validation or if I only have validation rules for the "native" `title` field (well it should, I simplified the code for stackoverflow and renamed some parts for the example, so maybe there are some typos, but you should get the idea...).

Now let's further assume the languages *English* (default) and *Spanish* are **required**, other language fields are optional. How can I achieve that?

In the `ItemsTable` I tried something like this for validation:

```php
class ItemsTable extends Table {
  public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
    $validator
      // Title English (default field)
      ->requirePresence('title')
      ->notEmpty('title', __('Required field'))
      // Title Spanish (translate behaviour field)
      ->requirePresence('_translations.es.title')
      ->notEmpty('_translations.es.title', __('Required field'))
      ;
    return $validator;
  }
}
```

But this allways brings a validation error "This field is required" because `patchEntity($item, $this->request->data);` results in the translations being thrown away. I know this by an open [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/4902) about the saving workflow (btw +1 for this request :).

So currently I'm not sure if there is a way to define validation rules for translation fields when using the CakePHP translation behaviour... *Required* language fields is only an example, the same problem occurs if you want to validate e.g. the min/max lenght of a input field for a foreign language...

Comment: My approach of the subjetcs here, if it can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426427/cakephp-3-1-my-validation-for-translate-behaviour-fields-need-some-help-in-re

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found a solution. At least temporarily, because I also discovered an [issue](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7532) with *NestedValidator* and *FormHelper*.

Currently the validation is still applied to **all** additional languages. So this is not exactly what I wanted and not the final answer. If you have an idea how I can apply the validation to single languages please leave a comment or answer.

So this is my current intermediate solution with `CakePHP 3.1.1`:

**In the table class add a [nested validator](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#nesting-validators) for the i18n translation fields.**

These nested validation rules will apply to all additional language fields, because they are grouped together in `$this->request->data['_translations']`:

```php
class ItemsTable extends Table {
  public function validationDefault(Validator $validator) {
    $validator
      // Title English (default language)
      ->requirePresence('title')
      ->notEmpty('title')
      ->add('title', [
          'minLength'=>['rule'=>['minLength', 2], 'message' => __('MinLength 2')],
          'maxLength'=>['rule'=>['maxLength', 255], 'message' => __('MaxLength 255')],
          ])
      ;
      // Nested Validation for i18n fields (Translate Behaviour)
      // These rules will apply to all 'title' fields in all additional languages
      $translationValidator = new Validator();
      $translationValidator
        ->requirePresence('title', 'false') // I want translation to be optional
        ->allowEmpty('title') // I want translation to be optional
        ->add('title', [
          'minLength'=>['rule'=>['minLength', 5], 'message' => __('MinLength 5')],
          'maxLength'=>['rule'=>['maxLength', 255], 'message' => __('MaxLength 255')],
          ])
      ;
      // Now apply the nested validator to the "main" validation
      // ('_translations' is containing the translated input data)
      $validator
        ->addNestedMany('_translations', $translationValidator)
        // To prevent "field is required" for the "_translations" data
        ->requirePresence('_translations', 'false')
        ->allowEmpty('_translations')
        ;
    return $validator;
  }
}
```

In my test setup I want the translation fields to be optional and have other minLength as the default language. As you can see in the code above, I added `allowEmpty` and set `requirePresence` to `false` for the translation fields. Currently the `TranslateBehaviour` is still forcing the translation `title` fields to be required. So I added additionally `'required' => false` to the translation input fields in add/edit form:

```php
echo $this->Form->input('_translations.es.title', ['required' => false]);
```

The separate validation rules are now applied to the translation fields, as shown in the debug result (added temporarily in the controller while testing):

```php
$item = $this->Items->patchEntity($item, $this->request->data);
debug($item);
```

When you enter only one character in the input fields, the `minLength` error messages are available in the debug error array.

**But currently the `FormHelper` does not support nested error messages.** I reported this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/7532). A temporarily solution to show an error in the form is by checking the `error` array manually. To do so, add in the Controller:

```php
$item = $this->Items->patchEntity($item, $this->request->data);
if ( !$item->errors() ) {
  foreach ($this->request->data['_translations'] as $lang => $data) {
    $item->translation($lang)->set($data, ['guard' => false]);  
  }
}
// Temp workaround for issue#7532:
else {
  $this->set('formerrors', $language->errors()); 
}
```

And in the add/edit view you can check and use the additional `$formerrors` array:

```php
if ( isset($formerrors['_translations']['es']['title']) ) { ... }
```

Another interesting approach is shown in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901123/cakephp-3-0-8-translate-behavior-and-data-validation-requirepresence-notempty).